# Show complex equation of closed curve integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I need to show this equation:
$$\frac{1}{2ia} \cdot \oint _{\gamma } \frac{e^{iz}}{z-ia}dz = \frac{e^{-a}}{2ia} \cdot \oint _{\gamma } \frac{1}{z-ia}dz$$  I have an hint to using Taylor.
I have no idea what to do. $$a>0$$ is a real number.   Thank you.

Comment: What you might be missing: Use the Taylor series _at the point $z=i a$_.

Comment: @Semiclassical why i should do it in that point? it's a pole of the function and inside the integral i have $$e^iz$$, i don't understand :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This identity is a direct consequence of the [Cauchy integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) if $\gamma$ is a closed rectifiable path. If it contains the point $z=ia$, both sides equal $\frac{1}{2ia}2i\pi*\text{res}\left(e^{iz},z=ia\right)=\frac{\pi}{a}e^{-a}$. (Assuming winding number = 1). If the point is not contained both sides equal zero.

Comment: Thank you! now i finally understand it

Answer (score 3):

Here is an elaboration of the hint provided. Consider the Taylor series of $e^z$ about the point $z=i a$: $$e^z=e^{ia}e^{z-ia}=e^{i a}+e^{i a}(z-ia)+\frac{1}{2}e^{i a}(z-ia)^2+\cdots$$
With this in hand, the integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{2ia} \oint_{\gamma } \frac{e^{iz}}{z-ia}dz=\frac{e^{ia}}{2ia}\oint_{\gamma}\left[\frac{1}{z-i a}+1+\frac{1}{2}(z-ia)+\cdots\right]dz$$
But every term save the first one is analytic in the complex plane, so integrating these terms over $\gamma$ gives zero. Hence we can drop these terms to obtain the desired identity.